# Chrome HTML5 Video Not Loading

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, html5-video

I have a video component in React that works for both Firefox and Safari, but it's not working in Chrome. Just as a sanity check, I created a fresh React app (below) and added a simple video tag, but the video would not load in Chrome and only loads in Firefox. How do I fix this?

```js
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <video
        muted
        preload="metadata"
      >
        <source
          src={`http://localhost:8005/video/test.mp4`}
          type="video/mp4"
        />
      </video>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

FastAPI endpoint

```py
@router.get("/video/{file}", tags=["video"])
async def get_video_stream(file: str, range: str = Header(None)):
    if range is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Range header required")

    start, end = range.replace("bytes=", "").split("-")
    start = int(start)
    end = int(end) if end else start + CHUNK_SIZE
    video_path = Path(f"/app/videos/{file}")

    try:
        with open(video_path, "rb") as video:
            video.seek(start)
            data = video.read(end - start)
            filesize = str(video_path.stat().st_size)
            headers = {
                "Content-Range": f"bytes {str(start)}-{str(end)}/{filesize}",
                "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
            }
            return Response(
                data, status_code=206, headers=headers, media_type="video/mp4"
            )
    except FileNotFoundError:
        logger.error(f"File not found: {video_path}")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Video not found")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my issue was that I needed to use a `fastapi.responses.StreamResponse`. Previously I was used `Response` to send back chunks of the video. I noticed that in the Chrome browser networks tab that it sent the same two requests to the backend that Firefox and Safari send before Chrome stopped sending requests for video data. That made me think that it's not getting the expected response back from the backend in those two initial requests - like a preflight options request - and so I considered looking into ways to change the backend and then found `StreamResponse`.

```
import mimetypes
from pathlib import Path
from fastapi import APIRouter, HTTPException
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse

router = APIRouter()
CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 1024

@router.get("/video/{file}", tags=["video"])
async def get_video_stream(file: str):
    video_path = Path(f"/app/videos/{file}")
    mime_type = mimetypes.types_map[video_path.suffix]

    if not video_path.exists():
        logger.error(f"File not found: {video_path}")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Video not found")

    async def iterfile():
        with open(video_path, mode="rb") as file:
            while chunk := file.read(CHUNK_SIZE):
                yield chunk

    return StreamingResponse(iterfile(), media_type=mime_type)
```

Comment: I know this answers your issue, but it doesn't really help anyone else. The question didn't even mention the use of python or a custom backend.

Comment: Apologies. I'll update my question with more context. At first I thought it was just a frontend issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use HTTPS: If you're testing on a local server, try using HTTPS instead of HTTP for the video URL. Chrome has stricter rules for HTTP content.

Comment: Do you have any links about this?

Comment: Just tried changing to https. Didn't work.
When I look at Chrome's Inspect Network tab, it shows that status of the video asset as "canceled". But after I see two Partial Content requests being sent before stopping. In Firefox, however, I see the same two initial requests, but after it requests the rest of the chunks of the video.